# fgetcsv brings all data in the first line

Tags: php, csv, encoding, fgetcsv

Using fgetcsv was the option that I found to read csv files that the system require. But it seems that it doesn't work every time (in reality its very rare when this code work).

```
if (($handle = fopen($file, 'r')) !== FALSE) {
    set_time_limit(0); // necessary if a large csv file

    $row = 0;
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ',')) !== FALSE) {
        print_r($data);
        // .. here I do some stuff with the data
        // .. The result should be an array with 5 columns and it run multiple times (for the amount of lines in the file)
        // .. The result however is one array with a over 9000 columns (really over 9000, it's 9489 in the file that I'm testing)
    }
    fclose($handle);
    die();
}
```

I tried to check the line end by calling this before the code, without much success.

```
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true);
```

The file is exported by another program by the client, and I can't have it "updated" to fit the need of the software. Is there a way to deal with this `encoding`/`line-ending` problem on csv ?

Comment: have you looked at the raw file to see what's in there? maybe it was generated with no line endings, or a totally non-standard end-of-record character.

Answer (score 0):

From the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) ( radical idea I know )

> length parameter
>
> Must be greater than the longest line (in characters) to be found in the CSV file (allowing for trailing line-end characters). It became optional in PHP 5. Omitting this parameter (or setting it to 0 in PHP 5.1.0 and later) the maximum line length is not limited, which is slightly slower.

I dont know what version of PHP you are using, but try setting the parameter to something sensible and you should start getting one line at a time.

Eg

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 4096, ',')) !== FALSE) {
```